# How to set a stop criteria for regex search in re.sub()

Tags: python, regex

I have a block of text and I want to remove phrases from it.

> "Adaptation" means a work based upon the Work, or `cAt` upon the Work and
>   other pre-existing works, such as a `f` translation, `DOG` adaptation,
>   derivative work, arrangement  of music or other alterations of a
>   literary or artistic work, or phonogram `f` or performance and includes
>   cinematographic adaptations or any

I want to remove any text between `cAt` and `f`, between `DOG` and `f` or between `rugrats` and `f`. I highlighted the terms in the text box for ease.

Each phrase (`cAt`, `DOG`, `rugrats`, `f`) has a space in front and behind it.

Here's my code

```
clean = `TEXT SHOWN ABOVE`
segment_start = [' cAt ', ' DOG ', ' rugrats ']
segment_end = ' f ' 

for start in enumerate(segment_start):
    clean = re.sub('{}.*{}{1}'.format(start, segment_end), ' ', clean)
```

I want to cut out

> "Adaptation" means a work based upon the Work, or <s>`cAt` upon the Work and
>   other pre-existing works, such as a `f`</s> translation,  <s>`DOG` adaptation,
>   derivative work, arrangement  of music or other alterations of a
>   literary or artistic work, or phonogram `f`</s>  or performance and includes
>   cinematographic adaptations or any

And end up with this

> "Adaptation" means a work based upon the Work, or translation,  or performance and includes
>   cinematographic adaptations or any

My code is making an error. It finds the start of the segment and then it finds that last appearance of the segment end `f` and deletes everything in between.

It does this

> "Adaptation" means a work based upon the Work, or <s>`cAt` upon the Work and
>   other pre-existing works, such as a `f` translation, `DOG` adaptation,
>   derivative work, arrangement  of music or other alterations of a
>   literary or artistic work, or phonogram `f`</s>  or performance and includes
>   cinematographic adaptations or any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*` is greedy repetition: "0 or more, as many as possible". This makes your first match grab everything from `cAt` to the last `f`, leaving nothing for the `DOG` query.

Use `*?` instead: "0 or more, as few as possible". This way, the regexp will be satisfied with "just" the bit between `cAt` and the first `f`, and the `DOG` regex will have its day, too.

Comment: I tried         `for start in enumerate(segment_start):
            clean = re.sub('{}.*?{}'.format(start, segment_end), ' ', clean)`, `for start in enumerate(segment_start):
            clean = re.sub('{}.?{}'.format(start, segment_end), ' ', clean)` and `for start in enumerate(segment_start):
            clean = re.sub('{}*?{}'.format(start, segment_end), ' ', clean)`

Comment: The function is no longer removing any of the phrases

Comment: The first one should. I am not at keyboard now to test though. `?` by itself is “0 or 1”, which won’t stretch between `cAt` and `f`; and in 3rd example you left off the dot, so it means “any number of cats followed by `f`”.

Comment: Got it. `'{}.*?{}'.format(start, segment_end)` was printing `(0, ' cAt ').*?` 
`(1, ' DOG ').*?`. I made segment_end into a list with the same length as segment_start and changed the loop to `for k, start` It's working

Comment: Ah, didn’t read close enough and took it upon faith that your code did what you claimed to do. Remove `enumerate`.

Comment: It's working. I changed it to `for start in enumerate(segment_start):
            clean = re.sub('{}.*?{}'.format(start[1], segment_end), ' ', clean)`